# Why MySQL table doesn't display date and time?

Tags: mysql

I have tried the following query to display time and date, but I am not getting the date and time in my table.

```
alter table users change time time timestamp not null;
```

```
| time                | userid   | groupid | jobs_running | jobs_pending | job_limit | run_failures | queues | atp  | pend_reasons |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | agutta   | 1       |            1 |          100 |       100 |            0 |        |    0 |            0 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | akawle   | 66      |           52 |            6 |         6 |          164 |        |    0 |            0 |
```

Comment: you got a wrong format upon inserting date time

Comment: Possible duplicate of How to Insert Data.

Comment: I believe reds & Drew are correct - the values in the _time_ field in the sample output you pasted appear to be formatted as timestamp values, but basically a value of `0`. If you didn't have `not null` I would ask if you want the default value to be the current timestamp... Do you control the `INSERT` statements? If so, check the value being inserted into that field. Do you want [`now()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-now/) to be inserted into that field?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing your `where` statement.

Comment: a where stmt where